Am I doing something wrong in making this gate bootstrapped switch?
I am following this Analog Mind article by Behzad Razavi (DOI : 10.1109/MSSC.2020.3036143), I am trying to design a gate bootstrapped switch which can sample 12-bits at 500MHz using the process described here in a 65 nm process node.
The Ideal SNR is around 74 dB for 12-bits (LSB = 1.2 V / 212 = ~0.3 mV) but I am getting nowhere close to it. I calculated the values of sampling capacitor assuming I will experience a 1 dB decrement in my SNR as compared to the 74dB value at 348K (75 degrees Celsius) and I got a capacitance of around 127 fF which I rounded up to 150 fF just to be “sure”.
Then assuming that I will have 0.5dB attenuation due to the RC behavior of the switch, I calculated that I need an NMOS on resistance of less than 50 ohms. So far, I just followed the calculations as instructed in the paper.
After which I made the ideal circuit in figure 1(a) of the paper with a battery of 1.2 V...with an input sinusoidal signal of peak-to-peak swing 1.2 V (-600 mV to +600 mV) at a frequency of (31/32)*250 MHz (i.e. near the Nyquist rate since I want the final switch to function at around 500 MHz) and my output spectrum's HD3 and HD5 values were nowhere near as good as Razavi's, best I could get was ~50 dB and 55 dB respectively for HD3 and HD5 with a very noisy spectrum. (All the spectrums I have aren't as clean as Razavi's, I even tried using a Blackmann Harris Windowing function.)
This was with a main switch whose resistance varied a bit from 12 to 14 something ohms (average was around 12.7 ohms), which I thought it shouldn't theoretically since we are bootstrapping the gate, so it should get rid of the resistance's dependence on input voltage. My best guess is it's happening because the threshold voltage for the NMOS is varying which results in that slight variation across an input voltage sweep of 0-1.2 V (I checked the transistor's operating region and the entire time it was shown to be in linear region)
As I keep proceeding through Razavi's suggested steps my HD3 and HD5 values keep getting worse and worse and the spectrum keeps getting noisier and noisier, i.e. the noise floor keeps getting higher. At around step 3 I gave up the process because my noise floor was around -45 dB and HD3 and HD5 values were around 36 and 48 dB, respectively. I figured I was doing something wrong and that this circuit wasn't gonna give me 12 bits of sampling any time soon.
To summarize, if anybody could help me with the following questions, it would be really really appreciated, I have just started studying about data converters :

Am I doing something wrong in following the design process suggested in the paper/ what am I doing wrong in designing the switch as described in the paper for my requirements ? And how can I correct these mistakes, please help.

Am I measuring its performance wrong? i.e. I have configured the process to compute the spectrum the wrong way around? I am using the functionality in ADE which allows one to compute spectrum of transient signals. I run the transient sim for 1 μs, and then I compute the spectrum. I have tried using both the regular rectangular window and the Blackmann Harris window with 3 bins....but it doesn't help with reducing the noise floor significantly. And besides the HD3 and HD5 values stay the same and I see quite high values for other spurs too.


Edit #1: After consultation with my prof, he has okayed that I can share schematic and sim results :
This is the gate bootstrapped switch I made :
M1 to M5 are 5x1u/60n (5 fingers each of 1u)
M0 (the main sampling switch) is 10x1u/60n (10 fingers each of 1u)
Sampling Capacitor (SampCap) is 150f
Boostrapping Capacitor (CB) is 200f
One thing I noticed was that for some reason when testing it with a DC input at VIN (varying from 0 to 1.2V) and CLK (cut-off in the image, its the pin visible as LK in the top-left) at 0V DC, the resistance of M0 varies like that of an NMOS and when I checked its region of operation it goes from 1 to 3 to 0 for some reason.....but from what I understand the operating region should be 1 (linear) all the time, right?

This is my Transient Test-bench with the gate bootstrapped switch

V0 and V1 are sinusoidal voltages at (127/256)*500MHz with a 400mV DC offset each with a peak to peak swing of 600mV and 180 degree phase shift (differential input has peak to peak swing of 1.2V)
V2 is the sampling clock at 500MHz square wave going from 0 to 1.2V
VDD is 1.2V
This is the output spectrum (rectangular windowed spectrum of differential output between OUT_P and OUT_N) :


You can't have signal voltages that go outside the supply rails. Specifically, you can't drive the source of the pass transistor below the voltage on its substrate. Try adding a bias voltage of Vcc/2 to the input signal.

@DaveTweed I simulated all the steps of the process with an added 600mV DC offset to both the input sources, but none of the outputs showed any improvement in the HD values or the noise floor of the spectrum that is still there.

Note that the paper says that given a minimum supply voltage of 0.95 V:

We assume a single-ended input range from 0.25 to 0.75 V, which translates to a least-significant-bit (LSB) size of 1 V / 1,024 ≈ 1 mV for the differential
ADC.

Your signal amplitude of 1.2 Vpp is simply too large for your supply voltage.

I am using a 1.2V supply. Apologies if it wasn't clear that the 65nm process takes a 1.2V supply and that is what I am using. So my LSB for 12 bits with 1.2V input range is ~0.3mV

But the point is, you need to limit the single-ended signal swing to about 50% of the supply voltage, or 0.6 Vpp -- say, between 0.3 and 0.9 V. The differential swing will then be 1.2 Vpp.

I have now added the schematic and some details of the final switch I made. Could you please have a look at those and tell me what am I doing wrong? I changed the voltage sources so that each source has a peak to peak swing of 600mV around a 400mV DC offset
